# Binomial distribution problem / biased coin toss

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I've got a text where the following statement appears:

You have a biased coin that has a 51% chance of coming up heads and 49% chance of coming up tails. Tossing it 1,000 times, you will generally obtain more or less 510 heads and 490 tails, majority of heads. If you do the math, you will find that the probability of obtaining a majority of heads after 1,000 tosses is close to 75%. The more you toss the coin, the higher the probability (e.g., with 10,000 tosses, the probability climbs over 97%).

This is a Bernoulli experiment executed 1000 times so we are dealing with a binomial distribution.

So doing the math (with python)

```
from scipy.stats import binom

n = 1000  # tosses
p = 0.51 # probability of head (coin is biased)
x = 501  # to get majority of heads out of 1000 tosses I need just 501
binom.pmf(x, n, p)  # scipy library

0.021451693818843456
```

And for 10000 tosses

```
n = 10000  # tosses
p = 0.51 # probability of head (coin is biased)
x = 5001  # to get majority of heads out of 10000 tosses I need just 5001
binom.pmf(x, n, p)  # scipy library

0.0011231912772331355
```

Assuming I'm wrong, where is my error?

Thanks

Comment: You got the probability of exactly 501/1000 heads and then exactly 5001/10000 heads rather than at least that many.

Comment: Thanks Ian, but to this you need to add probability of 502/100, 503/100, ... 1000/1000 (which is highly improbable), which is equivalent to what Henry said in his answer: 1 - binom.cdf(x-1, n, p)

Comment: ...Yes, that is what I meant. I described what you got, which was clearly not what you wanted.

Comment: Oh, now I understand ... thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the probability mass function when you should be using the cumulative distribution function or its complement

`1 - binom.cdf(x-1, n, p)` might give you what you are looking for.  Or you could take a sum

Comment: Thanks Henry, you are right